# What does 'flex-order' actually mean?

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

[Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/children) states that :

> Add the flex-order directive to a layout child to set its order position within the layout container. Any integer value from -20 to 20 is accepted.

What does `flex-order` attribute actually do? The statement above confuses me and the example given by them is also not very clear. Is this somewhat related to `z-index` property we have in CSS?

An elaborate explanation with a demo would be appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just defines the order (left to right, top to bottom) of the elements. Here's a simple example - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/VKpkEW?editors=1010#0). It is *not* related to `z-index`.

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp" layout-fill layout="row">
  <div style="background:purple" flex flex-order="0" flex-order-gt-sm="1"></div>
  <div style="background:yellow" flex flex-order="1" flex-order-gt-sm="0"></div>
</div>
```

We can see that the order of the elements changes when the screen size is lower or higher than width 960px.

From the [docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/container):

[image]